# i want to know the relationship between streamprovider and listviewbuilder

Tags: flutter

i have one question. I'm building a college community app using riverpod. I'm using firebase for the database. riverpod uses streamprovider to get the information of the documents in the collection stored in firestore, which I felt is similar to streambuilder. My question is related to this streamprovider. When I use streamprovider to stream documents to a collection and display them on the screen with listviewbuilder, if there are 10000 documents, shouldn't all 10000 documents be streamed at once? But I know that listviewbuilder doesn't get the information it needs to render the screen all at once, but only as much as it needs little by little.
So what's going on? The streamprovider is going to stream 10000 documents, and the listviewbuilder is only going to get the amount of documents it needs to display. I know these are common combinations, but I'm curious about the mechanics.

gpt said me some answers. but i can't entirely trust gpt
[image]

Comment: Please don't use ChatGPT as an authoritative source **for anything**: it only outputs what it read online and has zero capability to verify facts - and it's very easy to make ChatGPT contradict itself.

Comment: _"So what's going on? The streamprovider is going to stream 10000 documents, and the listviewbuilder is only going to get the amount of documents it needs to display. I know these are common combinations, but I'm curious about the mechanics."_ - did you consider that buffering might be involved?

Comment: If you stream a large amount of documents at once, the user's phone will lag.
listviewbuilder renders items on the screen only as much as needed, so if you use streamprovider and listviewbuilder together. 
I'm wondering if streamprovider can stream a large amount of documents and listviewbuilder can prevent lag on the user's phone.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between the two is that you can use the StreamProvider widget to provide a stream of data to the widget tree, and then use the ListView.builder widget to display the data in the form of a list. For example, you can use the StreamProvider widget to provide a stream of data from a database or API, and then use the ListView.builder widget to display the data in a scrollable list.